# Can we use result from one query as an input to another query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes in elasticsearch , and i have to send a query's result  as an input to another query ( the first query for the first index and the second query for the second index ) 
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Python
1. Send #1 query to elastic-API
2. Store #1 response in variable X
3. Send #2 query with variable X

Idea 2: Kibana
See if you can filter/query data in kibana and save the search as X

Then see if you can use X as parameter in new query inside Kibana as Y. Save Y.

See if you can call the Y result via API after you have verified it works in Kibana