# Use query result as parameter for another query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

How can I use query result of first query as a parameter to another query in elastic search

lets consider the dummy data

```
`PUT /_bulk`
`{"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"2"}}`
`{"name":"abc","old_data":20,"data":0,"old_data_id":"xy"}`
`{"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"3"}}`
`{"name":"def","old_data":20,"data":2,"old_data_id":"xy"}`
`{"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}}`
`{"name":"ghi","old_data":20,"data":0,"old_data_id":"yz"}`
`{"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}}`
`{"name":"jkl","old_data":18,"data":2,"old_data_id":"xy"}`
`{"index":{"_index":"movies","_id":"4"}}`
`{"name":"mno","old_data":18,"data":18,"old_data_id":"rt"}`
```

I'm using Elasticsearch , I'm trying to use a query result as a parameter for another query just like the result of this SQL query

```
SELECT name FROM movies
WHERE  old_data_id IN  (SELECT old_data_id FROM movies WHERE old_data \> 0 AND data = 0);
```

I am running all this query on my local host of kibana

I had tried to write sql query like this:

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "SELECT name FROM test_2 WHERE old_data_id IN (SELECT old_data_id FROM test_2 where name='abc')"
}
```

but i was showing error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "line 1:32: IN query not supported yet"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "line 1:32: IN query not supported yet"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

after research I found this post [Can we use result from one query as an input to another query in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041568/can-we-use-result-from-one-query-as-an-input-to-another-query-in-elasticsearch) but how can I implement it

I wanna write two separate query in elastic search in which first query will give all the old_data_id and in second query we will use this result of first query to find all the name corresponding to that id. How can we do so?
How can we connect two queries ? (Nested queries)
Do we have to store the result of first query somewhere and then use this ?
Do we have to use java or python if yes then how can I do explain if possible plz give code snippet?
Is there any ways to do it or it is not feasible?

Comment: one thing we  can do is -

1. execute first query. 

2. parse first query response. 
3. get second query.
4. modify second query to add first query response.
5. execute second query.

Can anyone tell me How can I implement it?

Comment: The Elasticsearch doesn't support select from select queries. But if you need particulary query, that you wrote in the post, you don't need this kind of query. You can use:  GET movies/_search
{"_source":["name"],"query":{"match":{"name":"abc"}}}

Comment: I had updated the table for better understanding, what actually I have to do is first I have to get all the old_data_id who'es old_data > 0 and data =0 then again I have to check in the same table which and all row have that particular old_data_id then give there names,
for example in the above table
first i will check old_data >0 and data =0
then It will give result old_data_id as `["xy" , "yz"]`
then i will check which all rows have these old_data_id
which will give resultant name as `[abc, def, jkl ]`(for old_data_id = xy) and `[ghi]` (for old_data_id = yz) can u please help @Vakhtang

Comment: GET movies/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "old_data_id"
  ],
  "query": 
  {
    "bool": 
    {
      "must": 
      [
        {
          "match": {
            "data": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "old_data": {
              "gt": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    
  }
  }
}
this query I had written to get old_data_id

Comment: Ok, now i undersood what you need... The "old_data_id" is not unique id and for one old_data_id can be more than one name. In this case you can't use one query. You really need to collect old_data_id in the first query (your query good right, but i recommend to use the "filter" inside the "bool" instead of "must"), and after that programatically generate the query from the first query results. Something like:  GET movies/_search {"query":{"terms":{"old_data_id":["xy","yz"]}}}